# What is the differencs between nodejs V4.2.2 LTS and V5.0.0 Stable

Tags: node.js, version, lts

Question as the title,What is the differencs between nodejs V4.2.2 LTS and V5.0.0 Stable?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/blog/community/node-v5/.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between 4.x LTS and 5.x Stable nodejs versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33661274/difference-between-4-x-lts-and-5-x-stable-nodejs-versions)

Answer (score 2):

nodejs V4.2.2 LTS : LONG TIME SUPPORT : as the word says you will have solutions to the bugs for a long time, that's more than **8 months**. SO you have lot of time to build app based on this version.

major changes can be seen from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v5.0.0/).

for head up node v6 is also coming in Q1 2016